# CSRF Rails5 — почему такой результат?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csrf

CSRF-защита представляет собой генерацию ключа на сервере, и запихивание его в формы и всё остальное во время запроса к серваку; если эти пришедший с запросом ключ не тот, это error, а когда одинаковые — 200 OK. Ежели не так понял, поправьте, пожалуйста.

у меня есть такой код

```
Class ChatController <ApplicationController
  def index
    respond_to do | format |
      format.html
      format.js {render js: "/ home / admin-iorigins / RubymineProjects / chatSimple / app / assets / javascript / channels / chat"}
    end
  end
end
```

во время его выполнения у меня такие логи

```
Started GET "/ chat / index? Format = js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-10 19:16:41 +0200
Processing by ChatController # index as JS
Security warning: an embedded <script> tag on another site requested protected JavaScript. If you know what you're doing, go ahead and disable forgery protection on this action to permit cross-origin JavaScript embedding.
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 3ms (Views: 0.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Почему это происходит?